Convert milliseconds to mm:ss:rrrr
How to convert milliseconds to mm:ss:rrrr where rrrr is the remaining milliseconds.

If you understand the way to get minutes and seconds, what have you tried to get the remaining milliseconds and what's keeping you from doing it?

There are 1000 milliseconds in a second and 60 seconds in a minute. Just do the math

It's pretty easy with a div-mod function that returns the integer division result and the division remainder.
60,000 milliseconds per minute, and then the remainder is whatever milliseconds is less than a minute, then just format out the result.


function divmod(a, b) {
  return [Math.floor(a / b), a % b];
}

function update() {
  const val = document.getElementById("ms").valueAsNumber;
  const [min, totalMs] = divmod(val, 60000);
  const [sec, ms] = divmod(totalMs, 1000);
  document.getElementById("result").value = `${Math.floor(min)} min, ${Math.floor(sec)} sec, ${ms} msec`;
}

document.getElementById("ms").addEventListener("input", update);
update();
<input type=number min=0 value=67890 id=ms step=42> milliseconds = <input readonly id=result>



